# FullCalendar.io jquery calendar does not render in production

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm trying to figure out why the calendar works fine in my DEV but when I push it to PROD it won't render correctly. I am calling out to the js and css files like this:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/framework/css/jquery-ui.min.css") %>"
type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

So I am at a loss why this is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to add asp.net tag to your question.  did you confirm the css file is at that relative path from your application root?  If the css isn't included in project with a Build Action, it won't copy.

Comment: They all have this and should be relative to the root of the application. Let me check the build action just to be sure it is doing that. Thanks.

Comment: That was it, these fullcalendar directory files were not in the project, duh!!! Ok, post your answer and I'll mark it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your CSS files are included in the project and have an appropriate BuildAction set so they get copied during deploy.

Comment: That worked, thank you for saving my hair from being torn out LOL